# NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[name="username"]"} in selenium JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to test a page using Selenium WebDriver and JavaScript. I want to console "SUCCESSFUL" after logging in by selecting elements and submitting the username and password, but I'm getting an error. Here is the code I have written so far:

```js
const {Builder, By, Key} = require("selenium-webdriver");

require("chromedriver");

async function test() {
  const driver = await new Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();
  await driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/auth/login");
  await driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("Admin"); 
  await driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("admin123"); 
  await driver.findElement(By.className("oxd-button oxd-button--medium oxd-button--main orangehrm-login-button")).click();
  const currentUrl = await driver.getCurrentUrl();
  if (currentUrl === "https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/dashboard/index") {
  console.log("SUCCESSFUL");
} else {
  console.log("ERROR");
 }
}
test();
```

Now when I run `node myfilename.js`, I get this following error:

```js
/home/metalhead/Desktop/testJs/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:521
    let err = new ctor(data.message)
              ^

NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[name="username"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=122.0.6261.94)
    at Object.throwDecodedError (/home/metalhead/Desktop/testJs/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:521:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/home/metalhead/Desktop/testJs/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:510:13)
    at Executor.execute (/home/metalhead/Desktop/testJs/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:443:28)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Driver.execute (/home/metalhead/Desktop/testJs/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:740:17)
    at async toWireValue (/home/metalhead/Desktop/testJs/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:146:15)
    at async /home/metalhead/Desktop/testJs/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:192:16
    at async forEachKey (/home/metalhead/Desktop/testJs/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:186:9)
    at async convertKeys (/home/metalhead/Desktop/testJs/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:191:3)
    at async Driver.execute (/home/metalhead/Desktop/testJs/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:738:22) {
  remoteStacktrace: '#0 0x560c89955e93 <unknown>\n' +
    '#1 0x560c8964dce6 <unknown>\n' +
    '#2 0x560c89698e48 <unknown>\n' +
    '#3 0x560c89698f01 <unknown>\n' +
    '#4 0x560c896dc3f4 <unknown>\n' +
    '#5 0x560c896baedd <unknown>\n' +
    '#6 0x560c896d9899 <unknown>\n' +
    '#7 0x560c896bac53 <unknown>\n' +
    '#8 0x560c8968bdb3 <unknown>\n' +
    '#9 0x560c8968c77e <unknown>\n' +
    '#10 0x560c8991b7cb <unknown>\n' +
    '#11 0x560c8991f7e5 <unknown>\n' +
    '#12 0x560c899090e1 <unknown>\n' +
    '#13 0x560c89920372 <unknown>\n' +
    '#14 0x560c898ed1bf <unknown>\n' +
    '#15 0x560c89944488 <unknown>\n' +
    '#16 0x560c89944683 <unknown>\n' +
    '#17 0x560c89955044 <unknown>\n' +
    '#18 0x7f4922294ac3 <unknown>\n'
}
```

Comment: Time to not assume elements exist or that your queries are correct: your code does not currently verify that `await driver.findElement(By.className("username"))` etc. actually return anything before calling functions on the result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the element did not appear to be in the DOM, and thus the  WebDriver could not locate it. In order to fix that, just write:

`await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.name("username")));`

This tells the WebDriver to wait until the element is located.

---

Other that that, some of you might have trouble finding an element by its class name when there are multiple class names present on a single element. Here's how you can do it:

`await driver.findElement(By.css(".oxd-button.oxd-button--medium.oxd-button--main.orangehrm-login-button"))`